# Cannot access $_GET variable in index file

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have been following a course online and I have been stuck for a few days with no help from the instructor. My controller works as follows:

htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]*)/?([a-zA-Z]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?$ index.php?controller=$1&action=$2&id=$3 [NC,L]
```

As you can see, the URL is broken up into controller/action/id. This all works great, but the problem here is that when I try to pass a get variable into the URL it won't recognize it. The image below shows what I mean:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[NC,L]` add QSA here `[QSA,NC,L]`

[QSA QueryStringAppend](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa)

Comment: OMG! You are a legend! How on earth did you know! A complete life saver. I cannot explain how happy I am. Thank you so much, enjoy your day!

Comment: @Maidul back in the days i had this problem aswell - it took me soo long to find out - ill never ever forget :D